# a pretty good download manager for windows phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, downloads

I should download a huge file from a web server. Downloading is usually slow or interrupted. For this reason I would like to know if anyone has developed a pretty good download manager so that I can complete my download. The operating system is windows phone 8.1

Comment: Have you tried with Internet Explorer on the phone as is? The operating system allows background downloads via a background service, but as all apps would be forced to use the same, I would expect IE to perform as well  (if not better) than any third party offerings

Comment: Of course I tried it with Internet Explorer. I do not think the download continues in the background, if I close the internet explorer tab

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use UC Browser on my Windows phone 8.1 to download files from Internet. It has pretty good download support with pause and resume functionality. 
You can download UC Browser from Windows Store on your phone.